# Python socket: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python, scala, sockets

I'm trying to hack together a way to send messages between two computers. The following code creates a thread for receiving messages.

```
import socket               # Import socket module
import threading
import traceback
def recv_one_message(sock):
    lengthbuf = recvall(sock, 4)
    length, = struct.unpack('!I', lengthbuf)
    return recvall(sock, length)

def recvall(sock, count):
    buf = b''
    while count:
        newbuf = sock.recv(count)
        if not newbuf: return None
        buf += newbuf
        count -= len(newbuf)
    return buf

host="ec2-35-160-33-3.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
kill_threads=False

def receive_thread():
    while not kill_threads:
        try:
            # Create a socket object
            soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)        
            soc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            port = 8502                # Reserve a port for your service.
            soc.bind((host, port))     # Bind to the port
            print("port bound")
            soc.settimeout(10)
            soc.listen(50000000)       # Now wait for client connection.
            conn, addr = soc.accept()  # Establish connection with client.
            soc.settimeout(None)
            print ("Got connection from",addr)
            while not kill_threads:
                msg_binary=recv_one_message(soc)
                msg=str(msg_binary, "utf-8")
                print(msg)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
        try:
            conn.close()
            soc.close()
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()

t2 = threading.Thread(target=receive_thread)
t2.daemon=True
t2.start()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-eaef71a53845>", line 59, in receive_thread
    msg_binary=recv_one_message(soc)
  File "<ipython-input-3-eaef71a53845>", line 7, in recv_one_message
    lengthbuf = recvall(sock, 4)
  File "<ipython-input-3-eaef71a53845>", line 14, in recvall
    newbuf = sock.recv(count)
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Here is my Scala sender that tries to connect to the Python part and sends "hello world" once a second.

```
import java.io._
import java.net._
import java.nio.charset.Charset

val host = "ec2-35-160-33-3.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
new Thread {
  override def run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        print("trying to establish connection")
        val soc = new Socket(host, 8502)
        val dout = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream())
        print("connection established")
        val serializedMessage = "hello world"
        val serializedMessageBytes = (serializedMessage).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
        while (true) {
          dout.write(serializedMessageBytes.length)
          dout.write(serializedMessageBytes)
          dout.flush()
          Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
      } catch {
        case e => e.printStackTrace()
      }
    }
  }
}.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        conn, addr = soc.accept()  # Establish connection with client.
        ...
            msg_binary=recv_one_message(soc)
```

You need to receive the data on the connected socket you got from accept (`conn`) and not on the listener socket (`soc`).